# Informatica: downloading image data type to disk

Tags: sql-server, informatica

I have a table in sql server that contain two columns

```
Filename char datatype
File image datatype
```

Requirement is to download all the data to the disk , is it possible using informatica and if yes how?

For example, if there are two rows in the table:

```
sal_1.pdf, <<image data>>
sal_2.pdf, <<image data>>
```

and it needs to be pushed to disk `D:/file_dump` directory then `D:/file_dump` should have two files with the names `sal_1.pdf` and `sal2.pdf`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `T-SQL` and `bcp` ([link 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx), [link 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337544.aspx)) like this:

1) Write a T-SQL script (using SQL Server Management Studio) to generate all shell/bcp commands

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT  'bcp "SELECT y.File FROM Schema.Table y WHERE y.IDColumn=' 
    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),x.IDColumn) 
    + ' queryout "D:\file_dump\' 
    + x.FileName 
    + '" -N -S SqlServerInstance -T -d "DatabaseName"'
FROM Table x
```

Press `Ctrl+T` (Text results)

Press `F5` (Execute)

Press `F6` (It activates the `Results (text)` panel

Press `Ctrl+A` (Select All)

Press `Ctrl+C` (Copy)

2) Create a new text file (`Win Key`+`Notepad`+`Enter`), `Ctrl+V` (Paste), `Save As ...` -> `dump_pdf.bat`

3) Execute `dump_pdf.bat` file